# Regex.Replace to change PHP define value

Tags: c#

I`m looking for regex syntax to check one pattern and change value in matched strings.

PHP have define function like:

```
define('KEY', 'VALUE');
```

but also PHP works for this scenarios

```
define ('KEY', 'VALUE');
define    ('KEY'  , 'VALUE');
define('KEY', 'VALUE'        );
define('KEY',       'VALUE')  ;
```

So if we have

```
define('KEY1', 'ChangeMe1');
define('KEY2', 'ChangeMe2');
define('KEY3', 'ChangeMe3');
```

How we can change value for key "KEY1"  via Regex.Replace?

Comment: I am thinking you probably did not want to tag this c#, right?

Comment: @TimHobbs I suspect he is processing a `PHP` file with `C#`.

Comment: Yes, i`m processing PHP file in C#

Comment: What about cleaning up the string?  If you are going line by line, remove all the spaces and just test for define('KEY','VALUE');  This would make your changes simpler.  Then you can reformat however you want.

Comment: So you only want to change the line with 'KEY1' in it?

Comment: @Derek Since there can be double 'define' in one line, logic is to parse character by character but i need to spend whole day

Comment: @Shar1er80 I think you got my point from this image http://prntscr.com/7cc4h3

Comment: So you're reading a PHP file line by line, and when you get to a certain line, based on a certain condition, you want to perform the Regex.Replace()?

Comment: @Shar1er80 i`m reading whole php content and just change some values, eq: http://prntscr.com/7ccgrr

Comment: The whole php content is in a single string?  I would have thought you would have it in a string array or a List<string>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79453/discussion-between-novkovski-stevo-bato-and-shar1er80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so ugly IMO, but it works.  Set your regex up to capture everything in groups, and then just replace the group that you want to replace with the value you want to replace it with.

Groups are defined by the open & close parentheses that don't have a `\` in front of them.

So in this case we have 3 groups:

- 1st group captures "define('KEY'," with any amount of spaces in between valid areas
- 2nd group captures the area you're interested in replacing
- 3rd group capture everything else after group 2

### UPDATE

Knowing now that you have the entire contents of a PHP file in a single string varible, try the following:

```
            string testPhp = @"
Lets put some garbage in here for testing purposes
define ('KEY1', 'VALUE1');
define    ('KEY2'  , 'VALUE2');
define('KEY3', 'VALUE3'        );
define('KEY5','VALUE5');
MORE GARBAGE
MORE GARBAGE
MORE GARBAGE

define('KEY4',       'VALUE4')  ;";

            testPhp = ReplaceValueRegex(testPhp, "KEY1", "TheNewValueRegex1");
            Console.WriteLine(ReplaceValueRegex(testPhp, "KEY4", "TheNewValueRegex4"));
            Console.WriteLine();
```

And `ReplaceValueRegex()` looks like:

```
private static string ReplaceValueRegex(string theString, string key, string value)
{
    // This is the group you're replacing ---|
    //                                       V
    string pattern = @"(define\s*\(.*,\s*')(\w*)('\s*\)\s*;)";
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(theString, pattern);
    for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mc[i].Value.Contains(key))
        {
            string stringToReplace = mc[i].Value;
            string replacementString = Regex.Replace(stringToReplace, pattern, String.Format("$1{0}$3", value));
            theString = theString.Replace(stringToReplace, replacementString);
        }
    }
    return theString;
}
```

Results:

```
Lets put some garbage in here for testing purposes
define ('KEY1', 'TheNewValueRegex1');
define    ('KEY2'  , 'VALUE2');
define('KEY3', 'VALUE3'        );
define('KEY5','VALUE5');
MORE GARBAGE
MORE GARBAGE
MORE GARBAGE

define('KEY4',       'TheNewValueRegex4')  ;
```

### OLD ANSWER THAT DEALS WITH A SINGLE LINE AT A TIME

```
// This is the group that you're replacing
// --------------------------------------|
//                                       V                                                           
string pattern = @"(define\s*\(.*,\s*')(\w*)('\s*\)\s*;)";

string string1 = "define ('KEY', 'VALUE');";
string string2 = "define    ('KEY'  , 'VALUE');";
string string3 = "define('KEY', 'VALUE'        );";
string string4 = "define('KEY',       'VALUE')  ;";
string string5 = "define('KEY','KEY2','VALUE');";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(string1, pattern, "$1Hello$3"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(string2, pattern, "$1ChangeMe$3"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(string3, pattern, "$1GoodBye$3"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(string4, pattern, "$1ThisWorked$3"));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(string5, pattern, "$1Action$3"));
```

Results:

```
define ('KEY', 'Hello');
define    ('KEY'  , 'ChangeMe');
define('KEY', 'GoodBye'        );
define('KEY',       'ThisWorked')  ;
define('KEY','KEY2','Action');
```

Comment: If we have "KEY2" how your pattern will looks like? I want to generate pattern per key.

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato You're referring to instead of "define('KEY'" you have "define('KEY2'"?  If so, this still works.

Comment: I mean what if i have multiple define with different keys in same text and want to change only 'KEY2' value

Comment: You misunderstand me, check my edited question, last words about given example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

use `\s*` for 'any amount of whitespace'

```
@"define\s\(\s'(.*?)'\s,\s'(.*?)'\s\)"
```